# How do I create a login form and response in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React.js, react-bootstrap and javascript.

I am trying to create a login page. So when the user types in the url:
`www.example.com/`- they arrive at the login page and the same when they type in `www.example.com/line-chart`

unless the user logs in, to which when typing in `www.example.com/line-chart` the user will then see a line chart.

**my login form looks like this**

```
<Form className="login-form p-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group controlId="formUsername">
                <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Username"
                    onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    type="password"
                    onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button 
                className="mt-5 mb-3" 
                variant="primary" 
                disabled={!validateForm()}
                type="submit"
                >
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
```

**my handle submit looks like this**

```
function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        let accountExists = false

        //checks if account exists
        for(let i = 0; i < mockData.userName.length; i++){
            let userNameExists =  (mockData.userName[i] === username) ? true: false;
            let passwordExists = (mockData.password[i] === password) ? true: false;

            if(passwordExists && userNameExists){
                accountExists = true
            }
        }
        if(accountExists){
            props.updateAuthenticationAndRedirect()
            debugger
        }
    }
```

**My app looks like this**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated:false,
      redirectURL:"line-chart"
    }
    this.updateAuthenticationAndRedirect = this.updateAuthenticationAndRedirect.bind(this)
  }

  updateAuthenticationAndRedirect(){
    this.setState( (state, props) => ( { isAuthenticated:true } ), () =>{
      return <Redirect  to="/line-chart" />
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route 
            exact 
            path="/line-chart"
            render={ () => (this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <LineChart /> : <Redirect to="/" /> }
          />

          <Route exact path="/" >
            <Login 
              authenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
              updateAuthenticationAndRedirect={this.updateAuthenticationAndRedirect}
              redirectURL={this.state.redirectURL}
            />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

I'm quiet unsure where to start any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the updateAuthenticateionAndRedirect() method.
You return a JSX element from a javascript function that is not inside a render method: `return <Redirect  to="/line-chart" />`

In order for your implementation to work, you also need to add a check inside the Login route like this:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={() => {
    !this.state.isAuthenticated ?
    <Login
      authenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
      updateAuthenticationAndRedirect={this.updateAuthenticationAndRedirect}
      redirectURL={this.state.redirectURL}
    /> :
    <Redirect to="/line-chart" />
  }
>
  <Login
    
  />
</Route>
```

Im not sure though, if this is the right way to do it. I usually use a variation of what react-router [suggest in their docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow)